# Why `\pdfstrcmp` shows unrecongnized command in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I have used this `\pdfstrcmp` as in the following to set the different

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setappendix}{Appendix~\thechapter}
\newcommand{\setchapter}{Chapter~\thechapter~} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\sffamily\huge\bfseries \color{sec}}{}{0.5ex} %
{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{appendices}=0
    \setappendix
    \else
    \setchapter
    \fi 
    \filleft \\%
     \titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{1ex}%
    #1\filleft\\
    \vspace{1ex}%
    \titlerule[3pt]}
   \makeatother
```

But I dont know for what reason, though it gives the desire output, it gives me the following popup in texstudio `unrecongnized command`. 
[image]

### Shall I ignore the popup?

If I dont, will it create any issues?

I am running pdflatex with Miktex 2.9 in Windows 10 machine (and using biber as backend with biblatex).

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setappendix}{Appendix~\thechapter}
\newcommand{\setchapter}{Chapter~\thechapter~} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}{}{0.5ex} %
{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{appendices}=0
    \setappendix
    \else
    \setchapter
    \fi 
    \filleft \\%
    \titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{1ex}%
    #1\filleft\\
    \vspace{1ex}%
    \titlerule[3pt]}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is usual Chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{This is appendix}
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Because the developers of TeXStudio forgot or didn't consider to include it among the know commands. Do it yourself.

Comment: Your editor is just like a pair of glasses. If you have a spot on your glasses, you don't think the apple in front of you has a spot. You can ignore it, unless LaTeX throws an error.

Comment: You have to worry about something if and only if it comes up in the `.log` file (as error or slightly less serious as warning). This is just your editor telling you it doesn't know a command. You only need to worry if TeX tells you it doesn't know the command in the `.log` file after an attempt to compile your document.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the answer and the confirmation. Kindly add the comment as answer and so I can accept it so that the question may serve its purpose.